# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS boots slow

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have a ThinkPad, t480s, and it is supported by Ubuntu pretty well. Upgrading from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18.04 brought me mainly advantages, but also 1 big disanvatage: boot time increased. I use password to login and while I boot my pc, it takes like ~5 to load on this ubuntu purple screen. This was not the case with Ubuntu 16. Same thing happens also on some HP laptops.

Here is the output from `systemd-analyze blame` :

```
          6.289s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.309s fwupd.service
          3.621s snapd.service
          3.315s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          2.241s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          1.347s plymouth-start.service
          1.059s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
           842ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device
           619ms apparmor.service
           572ms plymouth-read-write.service
           410ms docker.service
           390ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount
           380ms snap-core18-731.mount
           375ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
           341ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-352.mount
           318ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount
           305ms systemd-resolved.service
           284ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           274ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-82.mount
           271ms dev-loop13.device
           263ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
           259ms dev-loop10.device
           255ms dev-loop11.device
           247ms dev-loop15.device
           245ms dev-loop8.device
           242ms dev-loop12.device
           233ms dev-loop9.device
           233ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
           232ms dev-loop16.device
           217ms dev-loop14.device
           217ms dev-loop17.device
           211ms snap-gimp-113.mount
           209ms dev-loop18.device
           190ms NetworkManager.service
           186ms snap-core-6531.mount
           184ms dev-loop1.device
           181ms dev-loop19.device
           178ms dev-loop3.device
```

Comment: I faced same issues aftr upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. For me the plymouth service and network manager increased boot time significantly.

Plymouth service seems not to be a problem in your case, but maybe you can decrease boot time approx. 3 seconds with disabling it.

Disable the plymouth in grub with
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
and change the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT into
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth video=SVIDEO-1:d"


After saving the change you must update the grub with
sudo update-grub

and then restart the machine.